# clicking background-image from css

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to click on the background image which is defined in the CSS but not part of the html tag? I need to click on the div tag that has @class=hitLocation.

```
<ul id="uxFolderTree_uxFolderTree_template_TreeRootElement" class="ui-tree-root">
<li class="-ui-tree-branch -ui-tree-folder -ui-tree-type-root collapsible" data--selectionmode="None" data-level="0" data-path="0" data-rootid="0" data-parentid="0" data-id="0">
  <div class="hitLocation">
```

the CSS is

```
.ui-tree .ui-tree-branch.collapsible > .hitLocation {
background-image: url("/WorkArea/FrameworkUI/images/icons/plus.png");
background-position: 0 center;
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, no.

You can either:

1. simply click the `hitLocation` element. WebDriver implicitly clicks into the center of the element, so it might be good enough.
2. Use Advanced Interactions API and specify at which location in the element you want to click.

   For example, this clicks at position `[1,1]` counting from the top-left corner of the `hitLocation` element.

   ```
   WebElement hitLocation = driver.findElement(By.className("hitLocation"));
   new Actions(driver)
       .moveToElement(hitLocation, 1, 1)
       .click()
       .perform();
   ```